# any possible way to populate datagridview with large data faster?

Tags: vb.net

here's my code. it's already working. but populating datagridview is taking too long to fill.

```
Public Sub Reprint_Pop1(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal grd As DataGridView, ByVal display As Integer, Optional ByVal search As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal a As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal b As String = Nothing)



        Try
                cn.Open()
                Select Case i
                    Case 0
                        sql = "select pos.posno, transdate, transtime, sum(trans.qty) as totalitems, format(sum(trans.amount),2) as amount, printdesc from tblpostrans as trans
    left join tblpos as pos on trans.posno = pos.posno
    where pos.status = 'Completed' group by pos.posno order by transid desc limit 0, @display"
                    Case 1
                        sql = "select pos.posno, transdate, transtime, sum(trans.qty) as totalitems, format(sum(trans.amount),2) as amount, printdesc from tblpostrans as trans
    left join tblpos as pos on trans.posno = pos.posno
    where pos.status = 'Completed' and (transtime like @search or transdate like @search or trans.amount like @search or pos.posno like @search or printdesc like @search) group by pos.posno order by transid desc limit 0, @display"
                    Case 2
                        sql = "select pos.posno, transdate, transtime, sum(trans.qty) as totalitems, format(sum(trans.amount),2) as amount, printdesc from tblpostrans as trans
    left join tblpos as pos on trans.posno = pos.posno
    where pos.status = 'Completed' and str_to_date(transdate, '%Y-%m-%d') between @a and @b and (transtime like @search or transdate like @search or trans.amount like @search or pos.posno like @search or printdesc like @search) group by pos.posno order by transid desc limit 0, @display"
                End Select

                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("display", display)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("search", "%" & search & "%")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", a)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", b)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                grd.Rows.Clear()
                If dr.HasRows = True Then
                    Dim col(4)
                    While dr.Read
                        col(0) = dr("posno")
                        col(1) = dr("transdate")
                        col(2) = dr("transtime")
                        col(3) = dr("amount")
                        col(4) = dr("totalitems")
                        grd.Rows.Add(col)
                    End While
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgErr(ex.Message, "Error Encounter")
            Finally
                cn.Close()
            End Try
        End Sub
```

is there any way possible to optimize this ? like using adapter or binding datasource? if that's the way. how can i include it in the module ?

Comment: Why don't you use `DataAdapter` method?

Comment: i already did it earlier but it's just the same. i don't know if my code is wrong or i include it the wrong way. that's why i'm asking how can i include it.